# C++ console test app for a Runtime Component Library(C++/WinRT)

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

I need to create a C++/WinRT library for a BLE device. And also I need to create a test app for testing the APIs in the library. I am just a start learner of this new technology.

What are the different ways to use the C++/WinRT library(dll) functions in a C++ console test application?
If multiple ways are there, which one is better?

Could any kind soul shed some light? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to test a **Windows Runtime Component** in a C++ console application. The compiler will tell you that a reference to your **Windows Runtime Component** cannot be added to a console application because the two projects target different platforms. Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/create-a-windows-runtime-component-in-cppwinrt), you could learn that a **Windows Runtime Component** is callable from a **Universal Windows Platform**(UWP) app built using any Windows Runtime language(including C#, C++/WinRT, Visual Basic, JavaScript, and C++/CX).

I noticed that you mentioned Runtime Component and C++/WinRT library(dll), they are different kind of project in my opinion. The former should be a **Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT)** project, and the latter should be a **DLL(Universal Windows)** project. I don’t know which one you use, but the both two kinds of projects are not supported to be tested in a C++ console application. You could test them in a UWP app.

We suggest you use a UWP app to test your Windows Runtime component. For more information about UWP apps you could refer to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cppwinrt). You could also refer to the above document which shows how to reference a component in a UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

From 2012

You can use Windows Runtime Component (C++/CX) in C++ Console Application, it base on consume Windows Runtime metadata (.winmd) file, tutorial from Intel is [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications.html)

**Update:** From 2020

You can use C++/WinRT on Windows 7 (which are not include Windows Runtime like Windows 8 or Windows 10) too. It is new [C++/WinRT 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/news#news-and-changes-in-cwinrt-20)

> The cppwinrt.exe tool takes a Windows Runtime metadata (.winmd) file, and generates from it a header-file-based standard C++ library that projects the APIs described in the metadata. That way, you can consume those APIs from your C++/WinRT code.

This is [demo](https://github.com/kennykerr/win7) repository C++/WinRT for Windows 7 (author is Kenny Kerr - creator of C++/WinRT). In theory, it also work with Windows Vista, but now no one checking compatible.